# Python Classes, trying to grasp the concept of creating an instance of a class along with other class related functions

Tags: python

*Note this is not hw or a project. Found an old exam online and thought it would be good to understand* Did some review, but still fuzzy on this. Any insight on how to make sense of this would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What are you struggling with? The general concept of classes? Or do you just want to know how to use them

Comment: classes are like a variable/object template...it can be something like an int, float, list, dataframe, or somethin you've made custom because it doesn't exist in python already (i.e. a city)..just like a list will have a length, you can define attributes for your class, such as the name or state...defining a class lets you make instances of it..just like doing `x=int(1)` returns an int object, doing `x=City('Chicago')` will return a city object..you can then access its properties such as `x.state`..you can also define functions which perform an operation on the class instance (called a method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# a
X = City("Chicago", "Illinois")

# b - note this line of code would have to be inside of a function
return X.population

# c
X.county = "Cook"

# d - again, would need to be in a function
return X.state
```